# How low is "low DCR"?

Tags: inductor

I'm making a circuit with this PAM2401 IC to get 5V from my LiPo cell. Its [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/6/9/5/PAM2401.pdf) calls for a low DCR inductor (on the "inductor selection" section). How much DCR can be counted as "low"? How much is the scale we are talking about?

I accept answers in general since this is a general doubt of mine too, but I actually want to know specifically for this project.

Comment: To a certain extent, you can just ignore the word "low" as long as you calculate the power loss in the inductor and are OK with it. To a first approximation, assuming low ripple current, the power loss is Iout * Iout * DCR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually regard 100 mΩ or less as low DCR for switching regulator currents of one or two amperes. The PAM2401 can output up to 3A. It is mostly a matter of efficiency. If you select an inductor with higher DCR, it will be dissipating (wasting) more power.

Since \$P = I^2R\$, an inductor with 1 Ω DCR will be dissipating 9 watts, while one with 100 mΩ will dissipate 0.9 watts.

Most inductors for this application will range from tens of milliohms to a few ohms at most. Be sure to select one that is rated for the current.

Comment: More than that, but not by much -- the inductor current has a sawtooth character to it; the easiest-to-calculate case is if it's on the borderline between continuous and discontinuous conduction, in which case the RMS current is \$2/\sqrt{3}\$ of the average current.  So, 12W and 1.2W in that case (or less if it's more continuous, and more the more discontinuous the conduction gets).

Answer (score 2):

The evaluation board for PAM2401 chip has a 2.2 uH inductor rated for 6A, with 19.3 milliohms maximum and 16.1 milliohms typical resistance.

For comparison, the built in switching transistors are typically in the order of 100 and 150 milliohms.

The evaluation board sets the current limit to 3A, because it is a max 3A chip.

The inductor may actually be selected based on low resistance to get lower losses, it works as long as it is rated for more than 3A.

Comment: Great answer. Marking JYelton's as correct though, since it gives some approximately maximum value to consider, making it more general.